# Запись имени аудио файла в бд в конкретно данном случае

Tags: javascript, php

Вопрос заключается в следующем. Есть скрипт записывающий голос пользователя на сайте, нужно записать имя этого файла в базу данных(хочу понять в чем проблема с запросом), на сервер записывается без проблем, вот собственно код
Код для захвата звука с микрофона пользователя

```
    const URL = 'voice.php';
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'messages';
let start = document.createElement('button');
start.id = 'start';
start.innerHTML = 'Start';
let stop = document.createElement('button');
stop.id = 'stop';
stop.innerHTML = 'Stop';
document.body.appendChild(div);
document.body.appendChild(start);
document.body.appendChild(stop);
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true})
    .then(stream => {
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

        document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click', function(){
            mediaRecorder.start();
        });
        let audioChunks = [];
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable",function(event) {
            audioChunks.push(event.data);
        });

        document.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click', function(){
            mediaRecorder.stop();
        });

        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", function() {
            const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, {
                type: 'audio/wav'
            });

            let fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('voice', audioBlob);
            sendVoice(fd);
            audioChunks = [];
        });
    });

async function sendVoice(form) {
    let promise = await fetch(URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: form});
    if (promise.ok) {
        let response =  await promise.json();
        console.log(response.data);
        let audio = document.createElement('audio');
        audio.src = response.data;
        audio.controls = true;
        audio.autoplay = true;
        document.querySelector('#messages').appendChild(audio);
    }
}
```

Код для записи файла на сервер

```
<?php

$link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "astig", "0L8i1K6c", "fortestprog");


$uploadDir = 'voice/';
$typeFile = explode('/', $_FILES['voice']['type']);
$uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename(md5($_FILES['voice']['tmp_name'].time()).'.'.$typeFile[1]);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['voice']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile)) {
    $response = ['result'=>'OK', 'data'=>'../'.$uploadFile];
} else {
    $response = ['result'=>'ERROR', 'data'=>''];
}
echo json_encode($response);

mysqli_query($link, "INSERT  into users (audiof) values (".$_FILES['voice']['tmp_name'].")");
?>
```

Comment: В этом и проблема, я не совсем понимаю как взять это имя и записать при помощи sql

Comment: А где SQL запрос в PHP? если запись в бд

Comment: До сих пор не приходилось работать с медиа контентом и потому такие вопросы возникают

Comment: был бы очень благодарен если бы подсказали как это правильно сделатть

Comment: Кладете файл на сервер в закрытую директорию, а в базу пишете имя файла. При удалении записи из базы, удаляете и сам файл.

Comment: так вот как это имя записать на в базу? В моем запросе есть ошибка но я не пойму какая, если не сложно, можете подсказать?

Comment: Если вы будете имя файла юзверя писать в базу и на диск - то вас ждет весёлый сюрприз - ваши юзвери постирают друг другу файлы в один прекрасный день. Дайте имя или рандомное, или генератором SQL, на крайний случай - дата+время_с_секундами.